# Is it possible to delete the main device from Firefox Sync after reinstalling the OS?

Tags: firefox, sync

I recovered my data after a reinstall. But Sync still stores the data from the device that "doesn't exist" anymore. I can't find an option to delete devices like in Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see exactly what is your plroblem but may be you can find a solution here : https://account.services.mozilla.com/